# How to see section numbers in print preview in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

My document is a collection of certificates that are separated by sections.

I want to print a series of selected certificates (sections) and to print those certificates on one side only.

In print preview, Word shows an N of N count at the bottom of the screen, but (as far as I can tell) that count does not pertain to what one actually wants to print.

So, currently, I am "eye-balling" and taking note of the section numbers while in page layout view, which is a terribly inefficient workaround.

Is there a way to see section numbers in print preview? If not, perhaps someone has dealt with the same problem and has a more efficient workaround than mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "N of N count" at the bottom of `Print Preview` is the number of the current page and the number of all pages in the document (all of the pages that Word is previewing for you, for that document).  So you're right:  that may or may not be connected to what you actually want to print.  Most people, most of the time, are printing out all pages, so that is usually helpful to them.  And no, you can't change that.

These are some ideas that may be helpful for your situation:

1. You can put in some hidden text that shows you the section number, then specify exactly those sections when you print.  (I'm assuming you have print options set so that hidden text does not print.) You can put the (hidden) section number in the page header, for example, and make note of it when you're looking at the document in Print Layout mode. So if you want to print out sections 8 through 32, then in print preview you'd enter `S8-S32` in the *Pages* field. (You put ***S*** in front of a number to tell word you're talking about a section instead of a page.)

   You put the section number in the header by inserting the *section* `field`. (How to do that depends on what version of Word you have.)

   I'm assuming that by "section" you mean that you have an actual `section break` between the portions of text.  If you're using the term "section" in a more general sense, that won't work.
2. Using those same section numbers from above, you can print out a master document that shows those hidden section numbers and use that master document as an easy reference.  You'd do (1) as above, then change the `Print Options` so that you ***do*** print hidden text. (You need to make sure that doing so wont' change where a page break occurs.) Once you're done, remember to change the Print Options back so that hidden text does not print.
3. You can *select* all of the sections that you want to print, then in Print Preview, choose "Print Selection" instead of *Print All Pages*.  (Don't forget that you can use  to select non-continguous portions of your document.)

Comment: To aenw -- your answer is useful because it gives me three alternatives to find a more productive way of printing selected sections.

Your #3 suggestion was a revelation to me. I did not know that I could select non-contiguous sections to print!

Comment: Sorry that Word won't do what you'd like -- but so glad that you were able to learn something new anyway -- and that it sounds like it'll be something that will help make things easier.